# How do I automatically backup Mysql-Cluster database?

Tags: backup, mysql

I need to automatically and frequently backup Mysql-cluster databases. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Cluster includes an on-line backup tool that can be executed manually or via a script. For more information [read the documentation on the MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-backup-concepts.html).